# $ f(x) = 3^x+4^x-5^x$ has only one root

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponential-function, roots

The problem is to prove for the function:
$$ f(x) = 3^x+4^x-5^x$$
has only one root.

I know it isn't a hard problem, but I am really stuck on it so I would appreciate your help. I have calculated the derivative and calculated it to zero:

$$ f'(x)=3^x\ln(3)+4^x\ln(4)-5^x\ln(5)=0.$$
Dividing by $5^x\ln(5)$, we have
$$\frac{3}{5}^x\ln(\frac{3}{5}) + \frac{4}{5}^x\ln(\frac{4}{5}) = 1 $$

Then I see no clear continuation.

Comment: $ln(a) /ln(b) \neq \ln(a/b) $

Comment: The problem is to prove *what* for the function? That only one root ie solution for $f(x)=0$ exists? Then why are you setting $f‘(x)=0$?

Comment: Look at $g(x)=(3/5)^x+(4/5)^x-1$ if $f(x_1)=0$ then $g(x_1)=0$. Prove that both $(3/5)^x,(4/5)^x$ are decreasing hence $g$ is decreasing.

Comment: The only solution is $x=2$. Because $f(1)=1$ and $f(3)=-34$ so for the intermediate value theorem $f(x)$ must have at least a root in $(1,3)$. By exploration we can easily see that $x=2$. Studying the properties of the derivatives and the limits at positive and negative infinity we see that $x=2$ is the unique root.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$f(x)=0\iff 3^x \left(1+\left(\frac43\right)^x-\left(\frac53\right)^x\right)=0\iff\left(\frac43\right)^x-\left(\frac53\right)^x=-1.$$

Can you finish it now? (Hint: The LHS in the last equation is decreasing.)